# Exclude a table from Snapshot creation in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

Is it possible to keep a custom table from being added to snapshots outside of editing the snapshot definition?  We have a credential table for our cloud endpoints and customers keep replicating them in test companys via snapshot restoration.  We're going to create a custom snapshot definition but it would be better if we didn't have to educate them to use our custom option.

Comment: Snapshot definition is the only way I know -- would be great to be able to decorate the DAC with an attribute like [NeverSnapshot] and be done with it

Comment: Thanks Gabriel. Yeah I was hoping for some super secret attribute that would get the job done.